Error when using SQLProgrammabilityProvider when connecting to Azure?
in our project we have been using the SQLProgrammabilityProvider for quite a while now.
However when we try to build now when having our Azure SQL DB connection string in the code we get the following error.

This only happens when the connection string is linking to Azure DB.
If it links to a local database or any remote it works perfectly fine.
The connection string is in the following format:
Data Source=XXXXX.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXXX;Timeout=120;
Is there anything that we could at to fix this, cause this halts our entire development process.
Greetings,
Glenn

This was a great library, I've used it myself, but had problems with the latest versions of .NET (after 5, if I remember correctly).

We are still using .net5 thats the problem @JimFoye

Could you please share the code what you have tried?

The error occurs when the data stored in the SQL DB contains any JSON or any non-relational data. Try by saving some relational data in the SQL DB and use the below connection string format to connect the Azure SQL DB.
Try with the below code which connects successfully to the Azure SQL DB as you can see in the output below.
open System
open System.Data.SqlClient

let connectionString = "Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<adminName>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

let query = "SELECT * FROM SampleTable"

let executeQuery connectionString query =
    use connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    use command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
    use reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    while reader.Read() do
        printfn "%O\t%O\t%O" (reader.GetValue(0)) (reader.GetValue(1)) (reader.GetValue(2))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    try
        executeQuery connectionString query
    with
    | ex -> printfn "An error occurred: %s" ex.Message
    0 

Output:


Well we have been using the following library for a while
https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/
and its used across our entire project, we also dont have any data stored in our database as JSON type, its just when we try to connect to a Azure Database that this error occurs, the same database with the same data locally works perfectly fine

Once try with the above connection string format.
